# Why 2 <div> are considering different width of the screen for rendering?

Tags: html, css

https://jsfiddle.net/u74vyv7w/

Please refer code snippet in above link. I am trying to achieve fixed header, fixed left navigation holder, fixed right content holder, and scrollable middle content holder (scroll bar appear on browser window and not on div element). I am facing two issues:

```
div.middle {-webkit-calc(100% - 300px);}
```

1. Why there is a gap of 8px on both left and right side of middle content holder? Even after calculating width, it doesn't change (refer above code).
2. Why background color of middle content holder is not filling the entire space when content grows and exceeds screen size?

Stack Overflow doesn't allow me to post this question without code snippet so posting HTML code for reference. Associated CSS code can be found in jsfiddle link.

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header">
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="left">
            </div>
            <div class="middle">
                <p align="right">hello</p>
                <p>hello</p>
                <p align="right">hello</p>
                <p>hello</p>
            </div>
            <div class="right">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gap you are seeing is because the browser adds...

```
body {
 margin: 8px;
}
```

... by default.

You can override this in your CSS.

2. The height of `.middle` is not extending because you are using `height`. Try using `min-height` instead. Also note that you have a margin on the bottom of `middle`.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Le5kaw6u/)

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

div.container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

div.header {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #558c89;
}

div.content {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

div.left,
div.right {
  width: 150px;
  top: 50px;
  bottom: 0;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #74afad;
}

div.middle {
  margin: 50px 150px;
  background-color: #ececea;
  min-height: 100%;
}

div.content,
div.left,
div.right {
  height: 100%;
}

div.left {
  left: 0;
}

div.right {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Layout</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open Sans">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header">
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="left">
      </div>
      <div class="middle">
        <p align="right">hello</p>
        <p>hello</p>
        <p align="right">hello</p>
        <p>hello</p>
        <p align="right">hello</p>
        <p>hello</p>
        <p align="right">hello</p>
        <p>hello</p>
        <p align="right">hello</p>
        <p>hello</p>
        <p align="right">hello</p>
        <p>hello</p>
        <p align="right">hello</p>
        <p>hello</p>
        <p align="right">hello</p>
        <p>hello</p>
        <p align="right">hello</p>
        <p>hello</p>
        <p align="right">hello</p>
        <p>hello</p>
        <p align="right">hello</p>
        <p>hello</p>
        <p align="right">hello</p>
        <p>hello</p>
      </div>
      <div class="right">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't run a "reset css" most elements will have default style. In your case here your `<p>` got `margin` and `padding`

In your example I added a quick one by removing margin and padding to all elements by doing this css

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/u74vyv7w/1/)

I would look into something like [Normalize css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/)